# как записать в ссылку 2 переменные?

Tags: php

Есть такая строка

do
                {
                    printf("a href='test.php?sub=%s&limit=****'",$myrow28["id"],$myrow28["name"]);
                }

Как сделать, чтобы вместо `****` записывалось значение которое я ввожу с клавиатуры ?

Comment: мы не знаем, вы бы хоть привели код как записываете? что пытались сами сделать?

Comment: И при чём тут MySQL? да и PHP тоже - задачка-то для JScript.

Comment: Вводите-то где?

Comment: возможно теперь будет немного понятнее, расширил вопрос

Comment: нужно чтобы вместо**** вписывалась переменная, которую потом буду извелекать через get

Comment: Нет, вы так и не ответили, вводите-то где?

Comment: на этой же странице printf("<form method='get' action='test.php'>
     <p><input type='text' name='limit'></p>
     <p><input type='submit'></p>");

Answer (score 2):

При поддержке ES6 можно сделать так:

```js
function toUrl(strs, ...vals) {
  return String.raw({ raw: strs }, ...vals.map(encodeURIComponent))
}

document.forms.url.addEventListener('input', function () {
  document.querySelector('a').href = toUrl `//example.com?a=${this.a.value}&b=${this.b.value}`
})
```

```css
a:after { content: attr(href); white-space: nowrap; }
```

```html
<form name=url><input name=a> <input name=b></form><br><a></a>
```

Comment: хоть бы ссылку что ли дал на string templates и функции их меняющие :-)

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятен вопрос, но предложу такой вариант:

```js
let demo = document.getElementById('Demo');
let input_field = document.getElementById('Input_field');
let link = document.getElementById('Link');
let link_attr = link.getAttribute('href');
console.log(input_field.value)
input_field.addEventListener('input', function(){
 let text = link_attr + input_field.value 
 link.setAttribute('href', text);
 demo.innerText =  'Ссылка у тега <a> теперь такая: ' + text;
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
}
.wrapper input {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <input id="Input_field" type="text" />
 <div id="Demo">

 </div>
 <a id="Link" href="test.php?sub=%s&limit="></a>
</div>
```